# A new GPO states that "password never expires" but in Azure AD, no box is checked. Which takes precedence

Tags: entra-id

A new GPO states that "password never expires" but in Azure AD, no box is checked. Which takes precedence? If we change the GPO to add an expiration date and still no box is checked in Azure AD, will the GPO override no box checked?

Comment: Please tell us more about your environment and what you've already done to investigate this issue.

Answer (score 1):

**Password expiration policy**: If a user is in the scope of password hash synchronization, by default the cloud account password is set to **Never Expire**.

You can continue to sign in to your cloud services by using a synchronized password that is expired in your on-premises environment. Your cloud password is updated the next time you change the password in the on-premises environment.

**EnforceCloudPasswordPolicyForPasswordSyncedUsers**: If there are synchronized users that only interact with Azure AD integrated services and must also comply with a password expiration policy, you can force them to comply with your Azure AD password expiration policy by enabling the "EnforceCloudPasswordPolicyForPasswordSyncedUsers" feature

Source: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-password-hash-synchronization#password-expiration-policy